# how to get position of div in Mootools?

Tags: javascript, html, mootools

I'm a newbies in Mootools World and i'm learning it.I'm stuck in a small case of dimension. Here's my code, i was insert into jsFiddle:

[FIddle sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/rueta/ZHkAb/)

The code:
HTML
`<div class="container"><div id="animate"></div></div>`

mootools code:
`var pos = $$('#animate').getPosition();
    alert(pos.x);`

i can alert getPosition by oject, but went i get like: `myElement.getPosition().x` - this result = undefined :(.

Pls, correct my code, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your mootools code is wrong.

$$ is saying, `this.document.getElements()` (or `Slick.search` now) and it returns a new Element Collection (an array of elements with element prototypes).

`$$("#animate")` says, return a collection of all elements with id animate (I hope you have just one :-p). result of that is: `[object]` - a HTML collection. You then apply the `getPosition()` on that, which will also return an array of `[{x: nnnn, y: nnn}]`.

Anyway, this is why it is failing.

**How to fix**

when you mean to return a single element by id, mootools is very specific about it: use `document.id("animate")` or the shortcut for it of `$("animate")`. Notice that unlike jquery, the # is dropped here - it's identical to what the native js `document.getElementById("animate")` does, cept for it does more (like extend proto and assign uid).

when not sure, always console.log the result - it would have shown you the array.

**NB** you cannot get position or size on elements that are not in the dom, bit that goes w/o saying.

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/ZHkAb/2/